# What exactly is a false minoshiro in Shinsekai Yori?

Tags: from-the-new-world

I was quite curious to know what exactly a false minoshiro is.

For me, they seem to be some kind of bio-technology "machine" or cyborg or something of that sort, that has the capability of storing a lot of information. The reason I think they are not "naturally" occurring is because of the way they talk, which seems to be similar to machine speech. However, they also seem to be similar to living beings, because the false minoshiro was able to surpass the program denying access to its data in order to be spared by Saki and her friend. Basically, what exactly are they, and where did they come from? Is that ever explained in the anime or the novel?

Comment: About it overriding the login procedures, for advanced A.I. capable of independent decision-making, they can override lower-ranked constraints when faced with a higher-ranked directive. In the case, the children threatened to kill it, and its self-survival directive allowed it to override the login. Think of the three laws of robotics, there is a "... unless it contradicts law 1" clause.

Answer (score 5):

The false Minoshiro (lit. ミノシロモドキ, minoshiro-modoki, monoshiro-mimic) they encounter identifies itself as "Panasonic Automotive Archive, Autonomous Evolution, version SE-778H Lambda." About 890 petabytes of data is stored within it using holographic memory; this includes all 38,242,506 volumes published in Japan since 2129 AD and 671,630 reference books in other languages. The novel describes it to be a sort of flying transportation and search engine.

Because it allows easy access to the large cache of information, the intellectual elite are afraid that this forbidden knowledge might get leaked to the general public through it, and have made it a taboo to touch or even speak to it.